# Why is google's site identity icon a red lock?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, google

Why does google.com have this icon (see picture) for me? What does it mean?

Screenshot: Google.com. There are two lock icons. The top one is RED and the bottom one is green.
[image: on google.com I get the red icon]

Screenshot: Google.se. There are two lock icons. Both of them are green.
[image: on google.se I get the green icon]

As you can see, only google.com has the red icon, google.se has the green one. Although the certificates are not identical, they seem to be extremely similar.

Comment: Can you click the "Certificate Information" link and post both the certificate chain at the top and expand the details panel and post everything that's in there.

Comment: I think it might have been some problem related to the fact that google didn't redirect me to google.se (as it usually does). When I cleared all my browsing history (cookies, images, everything) from beginning of time, when I visited google.com I got redirected to google.se as I should, and everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 5):

***TL;DR:*** It's not red for me. It's probably a local issue which is hard to determine given what you've said thus far.

---

**Update**

Based on the *Certificate Information* screenshots, it appears you have the same certificates as me. There is a discrepancy between the exact date on which they expire:

```
My cert: *January 4 at 6pm*
Your cert: *January 5 at 1am*
```

which matches the discrepancy between your time zone (*UTC+01:00*) and my time zone (*UTC-06:00*).

It would help to guarantee the certificates are the same if you checked the fingerprint information for the certificates.

If the fingerprints are the same, please check another browser or two on your computer. If the other browser on your computer is all green, the issue is probably with your browser. You might try to update or reinstall the browser.

If the other browser also has issues, try another computer on the same network (preferably one that you are almost certain has no possibility of malware installed like a newly installed, updated OS). If the other computer is fine, the problem might be with your computer. Honestly, if I had a situation like this I'd wipe my computer clean and reinstall the OS just to guarantee there was no malware or critical mis-configuration. However, you may prefer to try to solve the problem without such a drastic measure at your own risk.

If the other computer on the same network is also red, stop sending any private information on this network immediately as this is a strong indication someone may be attempting to intercept your communication.

---

**Original Post**

Google Chrome has [four different Site Identity icons and four identical Connection information icons](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617). The red icon in the screenshot you provide falls under the Connection Information section of the Connection tab. These icons have the following meanings:

[image]

As you can see, the red icon is the most severe and specifically states the browser knows there are problems with the site's certificate. The description goes on to warn that you should exercise caution. Whether or not (as the description suggests) "someone on your network might be messing with the website" is uncertain, though possible. However, there might also be an issue with some other part of your network, with DNS, with your HTTPS settings, or something else. It's really hard to tell without diving deep into the problem.

What you should know though, is this is not normal. On my Linux computer in the midwestern United States running the latest version of Google Chrome, the identity is verified by *Google Internet Authority G2*.

[image]

Requesting your language, I get the same result (it's the same domain so it should not make a difference):

[image]

Immediately I can see the output your provided is different than mine. I have *No Certificate Transparency information was supplied by the server* while you have *Valid Certificate Transparency information was supplied by the server*.

Also, my connection uses *[QUIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC)*, while your connection uses *TLS 1.2* (though I don't think this matters).

In terms of the Certificate Information, both are the same:

[image]

I believe your language is Swedish (since I determined [sv stands for Swedish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), but have not determined the difference between *Svenska* and *Sverige*). Using the top level domain for Sweden, I get the same results:

[image]

And here's the Certificate Information on the Swedish domain:

[image]

Here's the basics about my browser version:

[image]

So at this point my answer is: ***it's not***, and that this might be an issue specific to your system/browser. Perhaps your browser does not trust *Google Internet Authority G2* as a certificate authority for some reason. Perhaps there is a network issue causing this. Perhaps someone is trying to intercept your connection. It's too hard to tell given the info provided.

However, if you can provide the output of Certificate Information (especially if it's different than what I have), that might be helpful to ruling out a thing or two.